# Wild card for ASP.NET bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I see `RegisterBundles` has some bundles by default:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
}
```

I want to add these two files too, but I don't know how to use a wild card:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerysignalr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"));
```

Comment: Have you tried `.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js));` and `.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js"));` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerysignalr").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR*"));
```

you can add `*` wherever you think you want the rest of the wildcard to go.

`~/Scripts/jquery.*` will load all javascript files that begin with 'jquery'

Comment: Oh so I think I don't want all the extra files get loaded each time

Comment: If you want specific filed you can do this: 
`.Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.another.js.library.js"));`

What this will do is load all the files under one script bundle.

Comment: Just to add to the above. You can't do /file*.js as it will throw a run-time exception in addition to showing a visual studio warning. I came here because I wanted to know how to load dynamic angular build files (the names change). I went for "~/file*" in the end which worked

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the default bundles, the * at the end of the jquery.validate script.

If you want to use a wildcard for your two new scripts, the common root is ~/Scripts/jquery*

Note that you'd have to remove the two default bundles since they share the same root, else they'll be double-registered and that could cause issues.